# Only half of the faces are displayed from an X3D file

Tags: blender, x3d

I'm new to X3D and I've been playing a bit with it, wanting to create a square mesh using a grid of vertices to later adjust the height of each vertex to create a low-poly slope or hill.

When I import my X3D file in Blender (4.0), I can only see half of the faces. More precisely, I can only see the even faces except for the face number 86 that doesn't show and the last one that shows.

Here's my X3D file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE X3D PUBLIC "ISO//Web3D//DTD X3D 3.3//EN" "http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-3.3.dtd">
<X3D profile="Interchange" version="3.3" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-3.3.xsd">
  <Scene>
    <Shape>
        <IndexedFaceSet solid="true" coordIndex="0 1 8 -1 1 2 9 -1 2 3 10 -1 3 4 11 -1 4 5 12 -1 5 6 13 -1 6 7 14 -1 8 9 16 -1 9 10 17 -1 10 11 18 -1 11 12 19 -1 12 13 20 -1 13 14 21 -1 14 15 22 -1 16 17 24 -1 17 18 25 -1 18 19 26 -1 19 20 27 -1 20 21 28 -1 21 22 29 -1 22 23 30 -1 24 25 32 -1 25 26 33 -1 26 27 34 -1 27 28 35 -1 28 29 36 -1 29 30 37 -1 30 31 38 -1 32 33 40 -1 33 34 41 -1 34 35 42 -1 35 36 43 -1 36 37 44 -1 37 38 45 -1 38 39 46 -1 40 41 48 -1 41 42 49 -1 42 43 50 -1 43 44 51 -1 44 45 52 -1 45 46 53 -1 46 47 54 -1 48 56 49 -1 49 50 57 -1 50 51 58 -1 51 52 59 -1 52 53 60 -1 53 54 61 -1 54 55 62 -1 55 63 62 -1">
            <Coordinate point="0 242 0 1 243 0 2 244 0 3 245 0 4 244 0 5 246 0 6 250 0 7 257 0 0 244 1 1 244 1 2 244 1 3 246 1 4 245 1 5 247 1 6 251 1 7 257 1 0 244 2 1 244 2 2 246 2 3 246 2 4 245 2 5 248 2 6 251 2 7 257 2 0 244 3 1 244 3 2 246 3 3 246 3 4 244 3 5 248 3 6 252 3 7 257 3 0 244 4 1 246 4 2 248 4 3 247 4 4 245 4 5 249 4 6 253 4 7 257 4 0 246 5 1 248 5 2 252 5 3 249 5 4 246 5 5 250 5 6 254 5 7 257 5 0 248 6 1 250 6 2 255 6 3 251 6 4 247 6 5 249 6 6 252 6 7 256 6 0 248 7 1 251 6 2 256 7 3 253 7 4 248 7 5 249 7 6 251 7 7 254 7"/>
        </IndexedFaceSet>
    </Shape>
  </Scene>
</X3D>
```

Here are some images showing the problem:
[Blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5i8t.png)
[view3dscene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZlA9.png)

I tried using a web viewer for X3D files and view3dscene instead of Blender but I got the same problem.

Also, in Blender I can see the faces from both directions, but in view3dscen I cannot.

Comment: The observation about not seeing the triangles from both side in view3dscene is because the "solid" attribute of the shape is set to "true" ; setting that attribute to "false" will direct view3dscene (and any compliant x3d viewer" to not perform back-face culling.

However, view3dscene will still show a lot of holes in the rendered surface, and I think it is because there is a bug or misconfiguration of the blender export to X3D. Please comment on whether you would be willing to share the .blend file